# MS SQL Server - Update table rows if it matches multiple conditions in columns in another view

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation which is quite similer to below depiction of example tables

I have "School" table

| SchoolId | SchoolName | PrincipleId | SchoolPrincipleName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | South Texas | 1 | Julia Petersson |
| 2 | North Texas | 2 | Schon Jakobs |
| 3 | Centr Texas | 3 | Elina Sherlock |

Above table has de-normalised column SchoolPrincipleName

There is another ViewSchoolWithOutPrinciple database view

| SchoolId | PrincipleId | IsSchoolWithOutPrinciple |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | True |
| 2 | 2 | False |

Now  i have to do correction of SchoolPrincipleName column in"School" table based on ViewSchoolWithOutPrinciple database view

I have to update SchoolPrincipleName column inside "School" table to empty or null for those rows which has SchoolId and PrincipleId existing in ViewSchoolsWithOutPrinciple and IsSchoolWithOutPrinciple is equal to True

Below SQL is symbolic representation so it doesn't meant to work.

```
UPDATE
    School
SET 
    SchoolPrincipleName = NULL 
WHERE 
    School.SchooldId     = ViewSchoolsWithOutPrinciple.SchooldId     FROM   ViewSchoolsWithOutPrinciple AND 
    School.PrincipleId   = ViewSchoolsWithOutPrinciple.PrincipleId   FROM   ViewSchoolsWithOutPrinciple AND   
    ViewSchoolsWithOutPrinciple.IsSchoolWithOutPrinciple = True
```

Can any one help in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use something like this:

```
UPDATE s
SET SchoolPrincipleName = NULL 
FROM 
    School s
INNER JOIN
    ViewSchoolsWithOutPrinciple v ON v.SchoolId = s.SchoolId
                                  AND v.PrincipalId = s.PrincipalId
WHERE
    v.IsSchoolWithOutPrinciple = True
    -- v.IsSchoolWithOutPrinciple = 1         -- if datatype is BIT
    -- v.IsSchoolWithOutPrinciple = 'True'    -- if datatype is VARCHAR(n)
```

Not entirely sure what that `IsSchoolWithoutPrinciple` column's datatype is - you might need to adapt the `WHERE` clause a bit

Comment: Thanks Marc your suggested query works. Thanks :)